# Benefit of indirectly allocating and initializing a declared @property

Tags: objective-c

When it comes to allocating and initializing objects that are declared @properties of a class I've seen two main patterns in various bits of sample code, so given the following (made up) header code —

```
@interface Class : Superclass {  
    Object *anObject;  
}  
@property (nonatomic, retain) Object *anObject;
```

The first, direct assignment:

```
self.anObject = [[Object alloc] init];
```

The second, indirect method creates a temporary object that is then assigned to the property and released:

```
Object *tempObject = [[Object alloc] init];
self.anObject = tempObject;
[tempObject release];
```

What's the benefit to the second method over the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between those two blocks of code is that the first one is a memory leak. When you call `[Object alloc]` you get "ownership" of the object, and are responsible for `-release`ing it sometime. Then when you call `[self -setAnObject]` it takes a *second* ownership, setting the retain count for the new instance to 2. If the method doing the creation returns without relinquishing its ownership of the new instance, you end up with a leak.

Try this:

`self.anObject = [[[Object alloc] init] autorelease];`

This works because `[NSObject -autorelease]` returns self and also schedules a `-release` call "sometime in the future" which usually means at the end of the current run loop.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that people are seriously suggesting the first direct assignment approach.

Comment: As hotpaw1 mentioned, I did have the first pattern wrong – I've not seen anything using the @property setter method, but I was fuzzy on the difference between self.anObject = [...] vs anObject = [...] anyway. But this makes sense - I'd forgotten that dot syntax affected retain counts.

Answer (score 2):

As a previous poster correctly pointed out, the first method (at least the way it's currently coded) is a memory leak. However the second method is technically more efficient because there's a bit of overhead associated with the autorelease pool.

Adding one extra object to a pool is probably not going to make a measurable difference, but adding lots of objects to a pool unnecessarily might, so in general the second method is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You may have typo'd the first pattern.  The direct assignment (to the instance variable) should be:

```
anObject = [[Object alloc] init];
```

bypassing the setter, and thus leaving a proper retain count of 1.

The bad thing is that it avoids the setter (thus causing potential code reuse/enhancement problems).

The good  thing is that it avoids the setter (important if this appears in the profile as a hot spot).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of why avoiding a setter is bad and/or good?

Comment: It's faster, as you're directly setting the memory, rather than sending a message to self. But by avoiding the message send, you also bypass the runtime magic required for things like KVC, property observers, and bindings.